# Bluetooth does not work every time on startup - Ubuntu 22.04, Asus BT500 BT adapter

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, asus

I got an "Asus BT500" usb adapter for my retropie machine running ubuntu 22.04. It pairs fine with my xbox controllers but on boot it will sometimes say, "Bluetooth hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout" and proceed to not work until I unplug it and plug it back in. I'm super frustrated because this only happens SOMETIMES, seemingly at random.

I even bought a different "Plugable BT 4.0" adapter, and I get the same issue but with different error messages. I've uninstalled and reinstalled bluez, blueman, and bluetooth multiple times, I've installed the official ASUS firmware for it and it STILL doesn't work correctly. I'm contemplating just reinstalling everything at this point before I smash it to bits. Please help if you have any idea what else I could do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.